# Core data: fetch abstract entity and filter by inherited entities relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, abstract

I have data model, with 4 entities:
1. abstract entity "Term"
2. two inherited entities from "Term" - "Section" and "Type" with defined relations to "Seminar" Entity

Here is my model (can't attach image here due to low reputation): [core data model](http://d.pr/i/XqYR)

I'm fetching entity "Term" and everything was fine. 
How can I write predicate to fetch entities where in inherited entities set "seminars" count > 0 ?
[NSPredicate preditcateWithFormat:@"seminars.@count > 0"] of course isn't working, because there is now definition of this relation in abstract "Term".

I've allready tried to move relationships "seminar" to abstract "Term", but I can't figure out how to define relations from "Seminar" entity to "Type" end "Section".

BTW, I'm using fetchedResultController in such way for UITableView cells/section/updates/notifications magic. I can filter results programmatically and fill controller model myself, but if there is any way to stay in *core data* paradigm it will be great.

In some moment Xcode get crazy and crashed until I've discarded all changes to the model.

My code is rather simple:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Term" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;

fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"vid" ascending:NO],
                             [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"vid" cacheName:CACHE_NAME];
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is there some reason that `Seminar`'s `section` and `type` relationships need to be to different entities? Merging `Type` and `Section` into `Term` seems like the obvious solution-- and then change `Seminar`'s relationships to point to `Term` and delete the `Type` and `Section` entities.

Comment: may be you are right, and i'm in captivity of rdbms paradigm. Seminar has to have several dictionary attributes (type and section), otherwise, this terms are imported from drupal taxonomy dicts and they have unique non-intersecting id's.

Comment: Finally, I've decided to filter results afterwards, when drawing tableview. It seems to me less painful. 
I've tried two methods: redefining as suggested to-many-to-many relation with several `terms` in `Seminar`, but it's difficult to filter results by several terms, i.e. `section` and `type` simultaneously.
Second, tried to move relations to abstract `Term`, and saved all logic with child objects, but model became too complicated also.